# R shiny: how to generate actionButtons sequentially depending on another main actionButton

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to generate some inputs for my UI depending on the value of an actionButton. Generating textInputs works fine (see reproducible code below), but generating actionButtons seems tricky.

Here is the code:

```
shiny::runApp(
list(
ui = pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("test"),
sidebarPanel(
actionButton("create","create")
),    
mainPanel(  
uiOutput('the_textInputs'),
uiOutput('the_buttons')
))
, 
server = function(input,output){
observe({
if (input$create == 0) 
return()
isolate({  

output$the_textInputs <- renderText({ #this works nicely
A <- paste0("<input id='A", 1:input$create, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='text' value=''>")
})

output$the_buttons <- renderUI({ # this does not work properly, probably due to the html commands here below not well specified
B <- paste0("<input id='B", 1:input$create, "' class='btn action-button' type='button' >")
})

})
})

}
))
```

Any suggestion or advice would be highly appreciated !

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `renderUI` you can only use "an expression that returns a Shiny tag object, HTML, or a list of such objects."

You must change for `output$the_buttons <- renderText` or in the `renderUI` function convert your strings into HTML : `B <- HTML(paste0("<input id='B", 1:input$create, "' class='btn action-button' type='button' >"))`

Comment: Many thanks ! it works indeed ! Just an additional question (sorry to exagerate): how can I specify the label ? This does not work surprisingly B <- HTML(paste0("<input id='B", 1:input$create, "' class='btn action-button' type='button' label = 'test'>"))